# Seg-Fault at BST remove() Function

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

Basically the program consists of a BST class that points to the first node of a Binary Tree, and the Nodes are also their own class.

The BST calls this member function:

```
void remove(const T& x)
{
    removeNode(m_root, x);
    return;
}
```

And this is the recursive part of the remove node, which runs to completion:

```
template <typename T>
void removeNode(TreeNode<T>* &p, const T& x)
{
    if(p == NULL)
        return;

    if(x < p -> m_data)
        removeNode(p -> m_left, x);
    else if(x > p -> m_data)
        removeNode(p -> m_right, x);

    else
    {
        TreeNode<T>* tmp = new TreeNode<T>;

        if(p -> m_left == NULL)
        {
            tmp = p -> m_right;
            delete p;
            p = tmp;
        }
        else if(p -> m_right == NULL)
        {
            tmp = p -> m_left;
            delete p;
            p = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = p -> m_right;
            TreeNode<T>* tmp2 = new TreeNode<T>;

            while(tmp -> m_left != NULL)
            {
                tmp2 = tmp;
                tmp = tmp -> m_left;
            }

            p -> m_data = tmp -> m_data;

            if(tmp2 != NULL)
                removeNode(tmp2 -> m_left, tmp -> m_left -> m_data);
            else
                removeNode(p -> m_right, p -> m_right -> m_data);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

I am seg-faulting right as the remove() function returns, and I would like to know why?

Comment: I'm still grappling with why on earth you're allocating a new node in a function that is designed to *remove* one.

Comment: its a temporary holder, so that I can rotate what value needs to be put where the deleted one was

Comment: Look at it carefully. If `tmp->m_left` is non-null, the allocated memory assigned to `tmp2` is outright-leaked as soon as you enter the while-body and overwrite `tmp2` with `tmp`. You need to revise your algorithm.

Comment: any ideas/references?

Comment: @SamPilla http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~holte/T26/del-from-bst.html

Comment: Edited my answer to show in details HOW your program comes to crash. Now it's your turn to tell WHY it does that.

Answer (score 1):

User @WhozCraig pointed out the most important error in your code: you allocate objects which you never use (and never destroy!):

```
TreeNode<T>* tmp = new TreeNode<T>;

TreeNode<T>* tmp2 = new TreeNode<T>;
```

The latter assignment causes the condition

```
if(tmp2 != NULL)
```

be **always** satisfied, which prevents you from executing the

```
else
    removeNode(p -> m_right, ...)
```

branch.

**EDIT**

Suppose you have a three-nodes tree with keys 2, 5 and 7. Let's denote nodes `node2`, `node5` and `node7`, respectively. Suppose `node5` is a tree root. Suppose also you're removing the key 5.
Then:

- `*p == node5`;
- first three `if`s aren't satisfied and control passes to the `else` branch;
- `tmp` is assigned `p->m_right` that is `&node7`;
- `tmp2` is assigned a new 'empty' object - let's call it `nodeEmpty`;
- `node7` has no children, so `tmp->m_left` is `NULL` and the `while` loop is skipped with no iteration;
- assignment instruction `p->m_data = tmp->m_data` causes `node5` to get key 7;
- as `tmp2 == &nodeEmpty` that is not `NULL`, you call

  - `removeNode(tmp2 -> m_left, tmp -> m_left -> m_data)`

which apparently is going to remove something from the **nonexistent** left subtree of `nodeEmpty` (?!), **BUT...**
But `tmp == &node7` at this point and `node7` has no children, so `tmp->m_left == NULL`. Consequently accessing `tmp->m_left->m_data` triggers memory access error and the process crashes before the recursive call to `removeNode`.